# Wine missing ntlm_auth 3.0.25

Tags: wine

I'm attempting to run a setup.exe file in wine which operates fine until I reach this error:

`err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.`

I've used winetricks to download the .NET framework (dotnet40) and DirectX (directx9), yet still run into this error. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 89):

I faced the same issue on Ubuntu 18.10.
I had to de-install & re-install package winbind

```
sudo apt-get remove winbind && sudo apt-get install winbind
```

and this error went out...
(another one remains, but that's probably another issue :

```
GnuTLS error: A TLS fatal alert has been received
```

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall winbind

Answer (score 0):

The issue can also be caused by one of the dependencies of ntlm_auth failing to run.

In my case for example, libsamba-util.so couldn't load because I had updated libicu, and samba was still expecting the older ABI.